# Application crash without any error

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, activitygroup, activity-manager

I have 2 classes phone and dialpad.java. In phone class i have 5 lines when u click on these lines the dialpad.java class will open.i want to run multiActivities in a single Tab like

i have home tab and in home tab the phone activity is show when i click on lines the dialpad activity show in home tab so i use ActivityGroup to do this.But the problem im facing is when the dial activity is open and i select an other tab the program is close without any showing logcat eror.

plz help me to solve this problem

```
public class Phone extends ActivityGroup 
    {
    public void ShowDialPad(int nFreeLineNo, String sPhoneNo) 
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Phone.this , DialPad.class);

        //   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
           intent.putExtra("LineNo", nFreeLineNo);
           intent.putExtra("PhoneNo", sPhoneNo);

           contentView("Activity", intent);

        //   startActivity(intent);
       }
    public void contentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
        {
            View obj_view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

            this.setContentView(obj_view);

        }
    }
```

Comment: you are not even starting the activity so how will this code will execute ?

Comment: there must be any errors in the logcat. Possible that You not opened the logcat window?

Comment: Darkie the activity is start in contectView function

Comment: Opiatefuchs there is no error in the logcat

Comment: when i run the app with simple startActivity() then the app will not crash

Comment: Instead of writing the insanely long line starting with `View obj_view`, write it in multiple lines and debug all the lines. I'm sure you'll find the problem then.